# Quote or bracket completion in bash, without pressing TAB

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, fish

Is there any way to have bash autocomplete matching symbols like `'"[{(` with their right handed counterparts?
I would like to do this without having to press tab.

For example typing the string `echo "` would immediately result in this string `echo "|"`, where my cursor (the pipe) is in between the two quotes.

*Bonus points if you can find a way that, when the first quote is deleted, the second one is also deleted.*

If you've ever used any mature text editor (eg. sublime text), you can understand how this interaction works. Answers utilizing fish shell are also accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Although you can not bind keys on itself in GNU Readline — something like `"(": "()"` drives to endless loop — there is a way. Not for `readline` in general, only for `bash`. Add this to you `.bashrc`:

```
readline-brackets() {
    READLINE_LINE="${READLINE_LINE:0:$READLINE_POINT}${1}${READLINE_LINE:$READLINE_POINT}"
    ((READLINE_POINT+=1))
}
bind -m vi-insert -x '"\"" : "readline-brackets \"\""'
bind -m vi-insert -x $'"\047" : "readline-brackets \\\047\\\047"' # SINGLE QUOTE
bind -m vi-insert -x '"<" : "readline-brackets \<\>"'
bind -m vi-insert -x '"(" : "readline-brackets \(\)"'
bind -m vi-insert -x '"[" : "readline-brackets []"'
bind -m vi-insert -x '"{" : "readline-brackets {}"'
```

Remove `-m vi-insert` if you use `emacs` mode, not `vi`.

Comment: This is a great tip ! However, although this works great for the normal case, I encountered 2 problems:

  * tab completions (ie: assuming `$FOO` is defined `echo ${FO<tab>} results in ${FOO}}`)
  * backspace handling (ie: '<backspace>' leave us with ') . Any ideas on how to handle these ?